# Return all rows from one table regardless of no data in other tables. Using Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a DB that handles reservations made against resources. I'm using `SSRS 2008 r2`. I've made sure that all joins in visual designer are showing all rows on `RESOURCES` table.

How can I return all rows from the `RESOURCES` table regardless of data in other joining tables? I'm using a `WHERE` clause with parameters of start date and end date. These parameters refer to dates on the `reservations` table. If I remove this from the `WHERE` clause I get all `RESOURCES`. However I need the start date and end date to be included so that I can search between two dates. I thought that if I did left outer join on `resources` table I'd get all resources. However, only getting resources with associated reservations made between start date and end date.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
```

(rows here)

```
FROM            
_ReservationsAttributes 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  _Reservations ON _ReservationsAttributes.ReservationId = _Reservations.ReservationId   
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
  _Resources ON _Reservations.ResourceId = _Resources.ResourceId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  _LocationsAttributes ON _Resources.LocationId = _LocationsAttributes.LocationId 
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN
  _Locations ON _Resources.LocationId = _Locations.LocationId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  _ResourcesAttributes ON _Resources.ResourceId = _ResourcesAttributes.ResourceId
WHERE
  (_LocationsAttributes.[@33] = @Distinct_Premise) AND 
  (_Reservations.StartDate >= @Start_Date) AND 
  (_Reservations.EndDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @End_Date))
ORDER BY 
  _Locations.OrderBy, 
  _Resources.Name
```

Comment: I seriously doubt *all* of your query is required to illustrate your problem. Please reduce it to the minimum query that shows the problem. It's currently mostly noise,

Comment: One way to debug the problem is to make Resources first table and then subsequently add one by one right/left outer joins . you will get to know which predicate On/Where is creating issue

Comment: Wow, I must admit, I don't comprehend this mix of left and right outer joins. Do you? Then: Do you really want all combinations of matching location attributes, ressource attributes and reservation attributes? This doesn't seem likely. This can be many records per ressource containing more or less the same data again and again. Don't you want to aggregate your data somehow? Your current problem, by the way, is that you have criteria in the WHERE clause instead of in the ON clause, thus turning outer joins into inner joins.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten Kettner. Moved start date and end date clause from WHERE to the join between resource and reservation and now I get all resources. Not sure I fully underdatnd how this works but thanks!

Comment: @user1022772: `from a left outer join b on some criteria` means: if you find no matching b record for an a record then keep the a record nonetheless with all b columns null. If in your where clause you ask something like: `where b.startdate >= @startdate` then this is never true for the outer joined records (null is not greater or equal a particular date). Thus you dismiss all outer joined records you just created and stay with what you would have got with a simple inner join.

Comment: @user1022772: You should take the advice given to rebuild your joins. Start with _Resources and left join all others. Your query is hardly readable.

Answer (score 0):

Deconstruct your query.  Start with only the central table (_Resources).  Add each of the other tables in one at a time, with the `WHERE` conditions.  Make sure each step makes sense before adding the next table in.

My guess - you are getting confused by using both `LEFT OUTER` and `RIGHT OUTER` joins.  We would need the schema to be sure.